# Convert Data frame with different date in list table into single dataframe using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, reshape, reshape2

I want to make table in list into single dataframe. I have data here

```
datex <- c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03")
x1 <- c(101,102,103); varx1 <- data.frame(x1,datex)
datex <- c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03","2018/01/04","2018/01/05")
x2 <- c(10,11,12,13,14); varx2 <- data.frame(x2,datex)
datex <- c("2018/01/01")
x3 <- c(1000); varx3 <- data.frame(x3,datex)
combination <- list(varx1,varx2,varx3)
combination
```

i want to have the result with "NULL" or "NA" like this

```
datex <- c("2018/01/01","2018/01/02","2018/01/03","2018/01/04","2018/01/05")
x1 <- c(101,102,103,"NULL","NULL")
x2 <- c(10,11,12,13,14)
x3 <- c(1000,"NULL","NULL","NULL","NULL")
answer <- data.frame(datex, x1,x2,x3)
answer
```

Need help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` with `merge` from `base R`.  The missing values will be `NA` instead of `NULL`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'datex', all = TRUE), combination)
#       datex  x1 x2   x3
#1 2018/01/01 101 10 1000
#2 2018/01/02 102 11   NA
#3 2018/01/03 103 12   NA
#4 2018/01/04  NA 13   NA
#5 2018/01/05  NA 14   NA
```

---

A similar option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(tidyverse)
combination %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = 'datex') %>%
      select(datex, everything())
#      datex  x1 x2   x3
#1 2018/01/01 101 10 1000
#2 2018/01/02 102 11   NA
#3 2018/01/03 103 12   NA
#4 2018/01/04  NA 13   NA
#5 2018/01/05  NA 14   NA
```

If we really need `NULL`, it can be placed within a `list` (not recommended)

```
combination %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = 'datex') %>%
      select(datex, everything()) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(matches('x\\d+')), funs(replace(., is.na(.), list(NULL))))
#    datex   x1 x2   x3
#1 2018/01/01  101 10 1000    
#2 2018/01/02  102 11 NULL
#3 2018/01/03  103 12 NULL
#4 2018/01/04 NULL 13 NULL
#5 2018/01/05 NULL 14 NULL
```

Comment: it works, but if want to make more general using "NULL", how should i do?

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba  I would recommend not to use NULL as you cannot store in a dataset.  It can be done in a `list` though

Comment: No problem.  Note that the columns are now lists because of the NULL.  Otherwise, you may need to convert to `character`, then the class of column will be character ie. `funs(replace(., is.na(.), "NULL")))`

Comment: Hi sir, i got a problem. I do with 100 x variables (x1,x2,x3,...,x100). I got message: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL". Can you help me?

Comment: @CarolusMardisonPurba  This is the reason I told you not to use `"NULL"`  What is the problem with `NA`?